# Hadoop - Mysql new API connection

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to set MySQL as input, in a Hadoop Process. How to use DBInputFormat class for Hadoop - MySQL connection in version 1.0.3? The configuration of the job via JobConf from hadoop-1.0.3/docs/api/ doesnt work.

```
// Create a new JobConf
JobConf job = new JobConf(new Configuration(), MyJob.class);

// Specify various job-specific parameters     
job.setJobName("myjob");

FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path("in"));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("out"));

job.setMapperClass(MyJob.MyMapper.class);
job.setCombinerClass(MyJob.MyReducer.class);
job.setReducerClass(MyJob.MyReducer.class);

job.setInputFormat(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormat(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
```

Comment: Most probably it doesn't work, because your code shows nothing related with `DBInputFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like the following (assuming the typical employee table for example):

```
JobConf conf = new JobConf(getConf(), MyDriver.class);
    conf.setInputFormat(DBInputFormat.class); 
    DBConfiguration.configureDB(conf, “com.mysql.jdbc.Driver”, “jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase”); String [] fields = { “employee_id”, "name" };
    DBInputFormat.setInput(conf, MyRecord.class, “employees”, null /* conditions */, “employee_id”, fields); 
    ...
    // other necessary configuration
    JobClient.runJob(conf);
```

The `configureDB()` and `setInput()` calls configure the `DBInputFormat`. The first call specifies the JDBC driver implementation to use and what database to connect to. The second call specifies what data to load from the database. The MyRecord class is the class where data will be read into in Java, and "employees" is the name of the table to read. The "employee_id" parameter specifies the table’s primary key, used for ordering results. The section “Limitations of the InputFormat” below explains why this is necessary. Finally, the fields array lists what columns of the table to read. An overloaded definition of `setInput()` allows you to specify an arbitrary SQL query to read from, instead.

After calling `configureDB()` and `setInput()`, you should configure the rest of your job as usual, setting the Mapper and Reducer classes, specifying any other data sources to read from (e.g., datasets in HDFS) and other job-specific parameters.

You need to create your own implementation of `Writable`-  something like the following (considering id and name as table fields):

```
class MyRecord implements Writable, DBWritable { 
    long id; 
    String name; 

    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException { 
        this.id = in.readLong(); 
        this.name = Text.readString(in); 
        } 

    public void readFields(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException { 
        this.id = resultSet.getLong(1); 
        this.name = resultSet.getString(2); } 

    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException { 
        out.writeLong(this.id); 
        Text.writeString(out, this.name); } 

    public void write(PreparedStatement stmt) throws SQLException { 
        stmt.setLong(1, this.id); 
        stmt.setString(2, this.name); } 
    }
```

The mapper then receives an instance of your DBWritable implementation as its input value. The input key is a row id provided by the database; you’ll most likely discard this value.

```
public class MyMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, MyRecord, LongWritable, Text> { 
public void map(LongWritable key, MyRecord val, OutputCollector<LongWritable, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException { 
// Use val.id, val.name here 
output.collect(new LongWritable(val.id), new Text(val.name)); 
} 
}
```

For more : read the following link (actual source of my answer) : http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/03/database-access-with-hadoop/

Comment: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBInputFormat
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.db.DBInputFormat
Try using one of them as per the API you are using.

Comment: i cant understand yet how to use 'public void readFields(java.sql.ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException' in the mapper to get the values... all the others seems to be ok... i am new in hadoop and java and i have been confused at this point

Comment: Sorry to reply late, did you refer the link I had in my answer ?

Comment: You need to create your own implementation of `Writable`: something like the following:
`class MyRecord implements Writable, DBWritable {}`

Comment: Yes, i developed the class... i have still problem in the main.. maybe in the configuration file of the DBInputformat... thank tou for your replies...

Comment: My Mapper is as below:   public static class RDFReducer extends Reducer<IntWritable,Text,IntWritable, Text> {
    private Text result = new Text();
    String res;

    public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      for (Text val : values) {
        res+=" | ";
        res+=val;
      }
      result.set(res);
      context.write(key, result);
    }
  }

Comment: i have datatype Int not long... i think its ok... maybe the mistake is in the database configuration,... I have two machines with two different Mysql with the same schema... I want each machine return its data and after aggregate them with the kwd field... i did it as you said... i think something is wrong in the main commands...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://shazsterblog.blogspot.com/2012/11/storing-hadoop-wordcount-example-with.html) post. It shows how to sink data from Map Reduce to MySQL Database.

Comment: i found the mistake and i answer it as comment below... thank you